# GUI application won't start in Konsole, opened in x2go session

Tags: gui, display, lxde, x2go

I'm using x2go server on my work laptop and pyhoca-gui on my home laptop. I open an LXDE session and start Konsole. Every app I try to run in Konsole fails to open the display.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer! I use byobu and started it in the previous session. After closing and opening it again everything works!